# How to get NHibernate.Type.IType from a Type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I try to do the following:

```
hibQuery.SetParameter("MyParameter", valueObject, valueType);
```

The only problem is that this method expects `NHibernate.Type.IType` in the third parameter, but valueType is of type `Type`. How could I convert this to IType?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the built-in `NHibernateUtil.GetSerializable()` method. It takes a CLR System.Type and returns the corresponding IType. More documentation: http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate/NHibernateUtil.html#M:NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.GetSerializable%28System.Type%29

Comment: I tried using:

`mapper.Type((IIdentifierType)NHibernateUtil.GetSerializable(typeof(DescribedEnumStringType<ExampleEnum>)));`

and it throws:

`
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in DAL.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Type.SerializableType' to type 'NHibernate.Type.IIdentifierType'.
`

even though `DescribedEnumStringType<T>` does override the necessary `IIdentifierType` members

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.GetSerializableType()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Use NHibernateUtil.GuessType method.

```
NHibernate.Type.IType type = NHibernateUtil.GuessType(typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fields/methods from the `NHibernate.NHibernateUtil` helper class.